# Convert user-defined pseudo regex string into working regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, .net-4.5

String to match `www.ads://fkdsmkdsf.mysite.comkmdfgkkdf`

Pseudo regex pattern : `*://*mysite.com*`

Desired regex pattern `.*?\://.*?mysite\\.com.*?`

My code:

```
string srinput = "www.ads://fkdsmkdsf.mysite.comkmdfgkkdf";
string srRegexPattern = "*://*mysite.com*";

List<string> lstRegexSpecialCharList = new List<string> { 
    "^", "$", ".", "?", "+", "(", ")", "[", "{", "]", "}", 
    "\\","=","<",">",":","-" };

foreach (var item in lstRegexSpecialCharList)
{
    srRegexPattern = srRegexPattern.Replace(item, "\\" + item);
}

srRegexPattern = srRegexPattern.Replace("*", ".*?");
bool blResult = Regex.IsMatch(srinput, srRegexPattern);
```

However, it seems like I am not making it correctly, because resulting regex fails to match my input string.

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Comment: Are you saying that given a pseudo-regex pattern (e.g. something a user might enter), you want to convert it to a regex pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex pattern that will match your input string is `.*?\://.*?mysite\.com.*?`. The double backslash `\\` will match a literal `\`.

You do not need any list for special character, `Regex.Escape()` does it all for you.

```
    string srinput = "www.ads://fkdsmkdsf.mysite.comkmdfgkkdf";
    string srRegexPattern = "*://*mysite.com*";
    srRegexPattern = Regex.Escape(srRegexPattern).Replace("\\*", ".*?");
    bool blResult = Regex.IsMatch(srinput, srRegexPattern);
```

The output regex is as expected: `.*?://.*?mysite\.com.*?`.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem:**

After all those replace calls your pattern string becomes `".*?\\://.*?mysite\\\\.com.*?"`

Basically, after `mysite` such pattern has to match one `'\'` character and some arbitrary symbol.

How can this happen? Let's take a look at your replace loop and the list with strings to replace:

```
List<string> lstRegexSpecialCharList = new List<string> 
{ 
  "^", "$", ".", "?", "+", "(", ")", "[", "{", "]", "}", 
  "\\", // The culprit
  "=", "<", ">", ":", "-" 
};

foreach (var item in lstRegexSpecialCharList)
{
      srRegexPattern = srRegexPattern.Replace(item, "\\" + item);
}
```

Yes, the culprit is the slash character string - after all those `"\\" + item` `srRegexPattern` will have a slash character that will be turned into `"\\\\"` on iteration when `item` becomes `"\\"`.

**Solution:**

Just replace all slashes at the beginning:

```
List<string> lstRegexSpecialCharList = new List<string> 
{ 
     @"\",  //All original slashes will be escaped and none of the "regex" slashes will suffer
     "^", "$", ".", "?", "+", "(", ")", "[", "{", "]", "}", "=", "<", ">", ":", "-" 
};
```

**P.S.:** In any case such solution looks a bit unreliable(there can be some not considered replacement cases ) and may have some performance problems due to the multiple `Replace` calls(can be solved with dictionary lookup for replacement strings and more streamlined pattern building (for example with StringBuilder)).